# Merging Long-Form Data that has NAs with Wide-Form Complete Data To Override NAs

Tags: r, merge, melt

So I have three data sets that I need to merge. These contain school data and read/math scores for grades 4 and 5. One of them is a long form data set that has a lot of missingness in some variables (yes, I do need the data in long form) and the other two have the full missing data in wide form. All of these data frames contain a column that has an unique ID number for each individual in the database.

Here is a full reproducible example that generates a small example of the types of data.frames I am working with... The three data frames that I need to use are the following: `school_lf`, `school4` and `school5`. `school_lf` has the long form data with NAs and `school4` and `school5` are the dfs I need to use to populate the NA's in this long form data (by `id` and `grade`)

```
set.seed(890)
school <- NULL
school$id <-sample(102938:999999, 100) 
school$selected <-sample(0:1, 100, replace = T)
school$math4 <- sample(400:500, 100)
school$math5 <- sample(400:500, 100)
school$read4 <- sample(400:500, 100)
school$read5 <- sample(400:500, 100)
school <- as.data.frame(school)

# Delete observations at random from the school df

indm4 <- which(school$math4 %in% sample(school$math4, 25))
school$math4[indm4] <- NA

indm5 <- which(school$math5 %in% sample(school$math5, 50))
school$math5[indm5] <- NA

indr4 <- which(school$read4 %in% sample(school$read4, 70))
school$read4[indr4] <- NA

indr5 <- which(school$read5 %in% sample(school$read5, 81))
school$read5[indr5] <- NA

# Separate Read and Math
read <- as.data.frame(subset(school, select = -c(math4, math5)))
math <- as.data.frame(subset(school, select = -c(read4, read5)))

# Now turn this into long form data...
clr <- melt(read, id.vars = c("id", "selected"),  variable.name = "variable", value.name = "readscore")  
clm <- melt(math, id.vars = c("id", "selected"), value.name = "mathscore")

# Clean up the grades for each of these...
clr$grade <- ifelse(clr$variable == "read4", 4,
             ifelse(clr$variable == "read5", 5, NA))

clm$grade <- ifelse(clm$variable == "math4", 4,
             ifelse(clm$variable == "math5", 5, NA))

# Put all these in one df
school_lf <-cbind(clm, clr$readscore) 
school_lf$readscore <- school_lf$`clr$readscore` # renames
school_lf$`clr$readscore` <- NULL # deletes
school_lf$variable <- NULL # deletes

###############


# Generate the 2 data frames with IDs that have the full data

set.seed(890)
school4 <- NULL
school4$id <-sample(102938:999999, 100) 
school4$selected <-sample(0:1, 100, replace = T)
school4$math4 <- sample(400:500, 100)
school4$read4 <- sample(400:500, 100)
school4$grade <- 4
school4 <- as.data.frame(school4)


set.seed(890)
school5 <- NULL
school5$id <-sample(102938:999999, 100) 
school5$selected <-sample(0:1, 100, replace = T)
school5$math5 <- sample(400:500, 100)
school5$read5 <- sample(400:500, 100)
school5$grade <- 5
school5 <- as.data.frame(school5)
```

I need to merge the wide-form data into the long-form data to replace the NAs with the actual values. I have tried the code below, but it introduces several columns instead of merging the read scores and the math scores where there's NA's. I simply need one column with the read scores and one with the math scores, instead of six separate columns (`read.x`, `read.y`, `math.x`, `math.y`, `mathscore` and `readscore`).

```
   sch <- merge(school_lf, school4, by = c("id", "grade", "selected"), all = T) 
sch <- merge(sch, school5, by = c("id", "grade", "selected"), all = T)
```

Any help is highly appreciated! I've been trying to solve this for hours now and haven't made any progress (so figured I'd ask here)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `coalesce` function from `dplyr`. If a value in the first vector is NA, it will see if the value at the same position in the second vector is not NA and select it. If again NA, it goes to the third.

```
library(dplyr)
sch %>% mutate(mathscore = coalesce(mathscore, math4, math5)) %>%
   mutate(readscore = coalesce(readscore, read4, read5)) %>% 
   select(id:readscore)
```

Comment: thanks for the response! that function looks neat, but I'm having trouble understanding what it's doing... I tried to run it with the sample data and it gives me this error: `Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : object 'math4' not found`

Comment: Then you are probably running it on a different data set. It just says that math4 is not is not in de data set you are applying the function on.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I just tried to do this approach on my actual data and it does not work because the replacement data also has some NAs and, as a result, the dfs I try to do `coalesce` with have differing number of rows... Back to square one.

I was able to figure this out with the following code (albeit it's not the most elegant or straight-forward ,and @Edwin's response helped point me in the right direction. Any suggestions on how to make this code more elegant and efficient are more than welcome!

```
# Idea: put both in long form and stack on top of one another... then merge like that!

sch4r <- as.data.frame(subset(school4, select = -c(mathscore)))
sch4m <- as.data.frame(subset(school4, select = -c(readscore)))

sch5r <- as.data.frame(subset(school5, select = -c(mathscore)))
sch5m <- as.data.frame(subset(school5, select = -c(readscore)))


# Put these in LF
sch4r_lf <- melt(sch4r, id.vars = c("id", "selected", "grade"), value.name = "readscore")
sch4m_lf <- melt(sch4m, id.vars = c("id", "selected", "grade"), value.name = "mathscore")

sch5r_lf <- melt(sch5r, id.vars = c("id", "selected", "grade"), value.name = "readscore")
sch5m_lf <- melt(sch5m, id.vars = c("id", "selected", "grade"), value.name = "mathscore")

# Combine in one DF
sch_full_4 <-cbind(sch4r_lf, sch4m_lf$mathscore)
sch_full_4$mathscore <- sch_full_4$`sch4m_lf$mathscore`
sch_full_4$`sch4m_lf$mathscore` <- NULL # deletes
sch_full_4$variable <- NULL

sch_full_5 <- cbind(sch5r_lf, sch5m$mathscore)
sch_full_5$mathscore <- sch_full_5$`sch5m$mathscore`
sch_full_5$`sch5m$mathscore` <- NULL
sch_full_5$variable <- NULL

# Stack together
sch_full <- rbind(sch_full_4,sch_full_5)
sch_full$selected <- NULL # delete this column...

# MERGE together
final_school_math <- mutate(school_lf, mathscore = coalesce(school_lf$mathscore, sch_full$mathscore))
final_school_read <- mutate(school_lf, readscore = coalesce(school_lf$readscore, sch_full$readscore))

final_df <- cbind(final_school_math, final_school_read$readscore)
final_df$readscore <- final_df$`final_school_read$readscore`
final_df$`final_school_read$readscore` <- NULL
```